# AWS CLI create-template json parse error

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ses

Trying to create an AWS SES template for sending personalized emails, but the CLI is complaining that the JSON can't be parsed?

I have verified the JSON and it is all good, not sure why it won't parse it?

[image]

Comment: Based on the screenshot, you have a weird character in the beginning of the template. Can you look at that.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too, but when I open the file in Notepad++ there is no weird character in the beginning of the file?

Comment: When I open the file in a browser, it renders fine. Validators also says its fine. But yes, I see that char there and its strange.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I had to convert to UTF-8 without BOM in Notepad++. That first weird character was the BOM.